# opacity issue with GTK window using compton

Tags: gtk, x11

I have a program which render on GTK window using EGL and OPENGL ES APIs.
Within the same program i do it 4 times to make tiles of 4 videos.

In background i have started the compton.

Now when i start first video, it is made transparent(not as per my requirement). 2, 3, 4 video works perfectly. But if i kill the thread rendering first video and start again then it works as well OR after first video rendering when it is transparent if i kill the compton then also this first video work perfect.

There is something wrong with Compton it doesn't allow data to be transported to first screen or It makes data transparent along with window.

I am using below config with compton

```
backend = "xrender";
paint-on-overlay = true;
unredir-if-possible = false;
```

Window Manager on my system is openbox-lxde

Answer (score 2):

I have got a work around for this problem. Posting it here because it may be helpful to someone in future.

In short this issue was just happening because my first window was FULLSCREEN. when X11 window resolution get matched with screen resolution there is some property/attribute which make is transparent under the influence of compositor(here i am using compton)

If first, i create window of size 0, 0, 1919, 1079 and later resize it to 0, 0, 1920, 1080 everything is fine, window doesn't become transparent and showing data perfectly.

Still there is mystery, what is that attribute which make Full screen window behaving like that.  Will post if find that.

Comment: Just a little addition: I have run into same problem multiple times myself, on both Windows and Linux. Turns out that it`s unnecessary to make both dimensions smaller than the screen size, one (e.g. height) is sufficient. Furthermore, to avoid the user accidentally seeing the bottom line on the desktop you can make the window one scanline _greater_ than the screen height.